# Invalid character string partly recognized? c++

Tags: c++, sanitization, escaping, invalid-characters

BLUF: In this function, \' prompt the error message but not \?, Why?

```
char key[] = "\a\b\f\n\r\t\v\\\'\"#%&*;:<>\?/{|}~";
        if (strpbrk(*local_str, key) != NULL )
        {
            vico_param_out->out_valid = false;
            AfxMessageBox("L'identifiant de numérisation est invalide. Vous avez saisi des caractères qui ne peuvent pas faire partie d'un nom de fichier windows (\"#%&*;:<>\?\\/{|}~). Veuillez faire les corrections nécessaires.");
        }
```

This snippet of code is supposed to check if one of the invalid caracters is in the input string (*local_str). Works well with some of them, but if some characters like \? are in *local_str. it accepts it and do not show the error message. I don`t understand what`s happening.

Example: 
ABC is valid
AB' is not valid, prompt mesage for correction
AB? is not valid but falls through
A'? is not valid but also falls through.

Please help. I am indepted to this community.

EDIT: Problem solved. I would seem that this function works but another process which I was unaware of was catching the keys in local_str as shortcuts before the call to my function, hence the weird behavior. I moved my function to be evaluated when each keystroke is inputed.

My deepest apologies for annoyance.
Thanks you everyone.

Comment: Why does the key have duplicate items? You have \\, \?, \', and \" listed twice.

Comment: Is local_str defined as a `char**` ?

Comment: Are you intentionally rejecting the space character?

Comment: To save others the trouble, yes `\?` is defined to encode the question mark, and yes undefined backslash-escape sequences produce UB.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Officially "Escape sequences in which the character following the backslash is not listed in Table 6 are conditionally-supported, with implementation-defined semanics" --- If a compiler does not support something that's "conditionally-supported", it must give an warning.

Comment: @James: that's C++0x. C++03 says undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jesse no reason, y will take them out
@Potatowatter It was just to make them easier to read for now, the spaces will be taken out afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Running this code, all three invalid string produce the error message.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char local_str[] = "A'?";
    char key[] = "\a \b \f \n \r \t \v \\ \? \' \" \" # % & * ; : < > \? \\ \' / { | } ~  "; 
        if (strpbrk(local_str, key) != NULL ) 
        { 
            cout << ("L'identifiant ......"); 
        } 

    return 0;
}
```

My only guess is that there may be some mismatch between US-en and FR-fr character sets.

Comment: US-en and FR-fr (to be precise, LCID 0409 and 040C) both are supersets of ASCII, and should function identically here.

Comment: I`m using FR-ca to be precice, but I do not think that can cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

A simple program calling `strpbrk` with your given input does not produce the problem. Try changing to `char const key[]` to see if `key` is getting modified between uses.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies. The code is working fine afterall. Another process was intercepting local_str before my code was executed and throw a silent exception and skipped my function all together.

I moved my code to be executed before that said process and it should be fixed tomorrow morning.